# Navigating to the top of previous page in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some buttons in my Angular 8 app, which have to send the user to the previous page on click.
Everything works fine; however, the page is not being scrolled to the top when navigating back.
What can I add or edit to make this happen?

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
private _location: Location
...
public goBack(): void {
  this._location.back();
}
```

Comment: Use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` in `ngOnInit()` of your component that you want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular routing concept to route to a different component on click.

Angular routing concept link: https://angular.io/start/start-routing

I hope it works :) If not share your code I'll look into it to help you out.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using routerLink? My previous page has several tabs, and the path looks like: path: 'pageName/:tabName'. So there are several possible routes, depending on the last opened tab..

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `scrollPositionRestoration: enabled` in your router module.

Please refer this -https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration